# What process creates the schema if it doesn't exist?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, schema, flyway

I wonder if spring boot or flyway creates the schema if it doesn't exist?

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:6432/jpa?currentSchema=jpa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.flyway.user=username
spring.flyway.password=password
spring.flyway.schemas=jpa
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:6432/jpa
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Also in build.gradle I have:

```
defaultTasks 'flywayMigrate'
```

No answers in google.
I haven't got any schema creation in my first migration, only tables creation.
However, after starting my app schema is being created each time.

**UPDATE:**

I suppose the flyway is responsible for creating schema. Logs that I got in debug mode implies on it:

```
2023-09-06 14:05:22.121 DEBUG 22860 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbSchemas      : Creating schema: "jpa"
2023-09-06 14:05:22.122  INFO 22860 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.database.base.Schema   : Creating schema "jpa" ...
2023-09-06 14:05:22.132  INFO 22860 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table "jpa"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2023-09-06 14:05:22.133 DEBUG 22860 --- [           main] o.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.Parser   : Parsing  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway will try and create schemas defined in `flyway.schemas` if they don't exist, and [this behaviour is configurable](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/create-schemas-184127493.html) with the `createSchemas` configuration parameter